# WP7: Binding to attached properties

Tags: c#, data-binding, windows-phone-7, dependency-properties

I'm trying to bind a data value to an attached property. However, it just dont get it to work.

I defined it like:

```
public static class MyClass
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MyProperty", typeof(string),
        typeof(MyClass), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public static string GetMyProperty(DependencyObject d)
    {
        return (string)d.GetValue(MyPropertyProperty);
    }

    public static void SetMyProperty(DependencyObject d, string value)
    {
        d.SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Now the XAML I use it looks something like this:

```
<TextBlock local:MyClass.MyProperty="{Binding MyStringValue}" />
```

I set a breakpoint in the SetMyProperty method, but it is never called. It does not raise any error, it is just never set or asked for. However, if I change the value in XAML to a fixed string, it gets called:

```
<TextBlock local:MyClass.MyProperty="foobar" />
```

What am I missing?

Note: the above example is the minimal version that shows the same strange behavior. My actual implementation makes more sense than this of course.

Thanks in advance for any hint!

Comment: AFAIR even if the Get/set is necessary WPF/Silverlight might not call them directly. Thats why your breakpoint isn't hit, because WPF/Silverlight is using reflection(just a guess) or directly using SetValue. You said it won't work, is the value correct but your breakpoint isn't hit? Then its just normal. Sorry can't find the source of this in the MSDN, but i know i read it somewhere.

Comment: @dowhilefor: That would make sense. I just did not find anything about this as I searched for it...

Comment: There's a mistake in your get/set declarations, should be:
return (string)d.GetValue(MyPropertyProperty);

Comment: no it (silverlight) don't use reflection - it's the way the property-system works in WPF/Silverlight - the data is not in the object but in a kind of static-class bindings will change this values in there not on your instance and the getter/setter in the instance is using this too (GetValue/SetValue)

Comment: @Philip Daubmeier Finally i found it look for [XAML Loading and Dependency Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903933%28v=vs.95%29.aspx#checklist)

Comment: @cunningdave: Just a typo as I simplified the code for the example here. It was right in the actual implementation.

Comment: @dowhilefor: Thanks! I'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And the binding wont trigger your SetMyProperty ever - if you need controll over when the value changes you must use the override of [PropertyMetadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms557330.aspx) that expects a "Change"-Handler

```
... new PropertyMetadata(
    null,
    new PropertyChangedCallback((sender, e) => {
      var myThis = (MyClass)sender;
      var changedString = (string)e.NewValue;
      // To whatever you like with myThis ( = the sender object) and changedString (= new value)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the type of the second argument in SetMyProperty to type Object.

You are going to get a Binding object, not a String, as the value there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Just tried it, but it still doesnt work.

Comment: This is wrong. You never get a Binding object, his dp is of type string so also the SetMyPropert should expect a string. WPF/silverlight will keep track of how and when evaluate the binding to get the effective value for the dp or ap.